# Angular routes / router unable to get fragment when also catching parameters

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I am working on an angular web app, on the home page there are sections that use fragment for scrolling (intro, about, contact), I also have social logins using odic which return parameters (e.g. blah?=stuff_#) in fact I see a url with a long fragment prior to it when I login, which annoyingly starts with #.

I have found that the two do not work together, and am wodering if anyone can help me get around the issue?

I tried ngx-scroll-to but for some reason it didn't work at all. (Probably because I use ngx-sidebar which wraps the page content). If I disable one function the the other works, but never together.

in my app.component.ts the 2 functions are within ngOnInit:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
this.router.events.subscribe(s => {
  if (s instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      const tree = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url);
      if (tree.fragment && !tree.queryParams) {
      const element = document.querySelector("#" + tree.fragment);
      if (element) { element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "instant", block: "start", inline: "start" }); }
      }
  }
});


this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
  const param = params['externalLoginStatus'];
  if (param) {
    const status = <ExternalLoginStatus>+param;
    switch (status) {
      case ExternalLoginStatus.CreateAccount:
        this.router.navigate(['createaccount']);
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

}

as you can see I tried adding "!tree.queryParams" to the first function, which didn't help!

I was wondering if there was a way to put the functions together and process them so /home#intro etc is recognised as an anchor but anything else is parsed on to process for social login... I suppose I could test the fragment against some stored values and if its not in that then continue with the other function?? Any ideas welcome! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to combine them, and it seems to work;

I think the issue was that I was using 2 subscriptions... I can't be sure. Here's the code from my OnInit anyway on the off chance it may help someone else:

```
>     this.fragSub = this.router.events.subscribe(s => {
      if (s instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          const tree = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url);
          if (tree.fragment) {
              let element;
              switch (tree.fragment) {
                  case 'intro':                      
                      element = document.querySelector("#" + tree.fragment)
                      if (element) { element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "instant", block: "start", inline: "start" }); };
                      break;
                  case 'about':
                      element = document.querySelector("#" + tree.fragment)
                      if (element) { element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "instant", block: "start", inline: "start" }); };
                      break;
                  case 'contact':
                      element = document.querySelector("#" + tree.fragment)
                      if (element) { element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "instant", block: "start", inline: "start" }); };
                      break;
                  default:
                      break;
              }
          }
      }
      const tree = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url);
      if (tree.queryParams['externalLoginStatus']) {
          const param = tree.queryParams['externalLoginStatus'];
          if (param) {
              const status = <ExternalLoginStatus>+param;
              switch (status) {
                  case ExternalLoginStatus.CreateAccount:
                      this.router.navigate(['createaccount']);
                      break;

                  default:
                      break;
              }
          }
      }
    });
```